# undefined references during link phase using Boost 1.53

Tags: c++, linux, boost, redhat

I am using g++ 4.1.2 and Boost 1.53 on Red Hat Linux rel 5.5. There is an issue during the linking process which is unclear to me. I get the error msg:

```
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so: 
 undefined reference to     `std::bad_exception::what() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.9'

/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so: 
undefined reference to `std::bad_alloc::what() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.9'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There seems to be a problem related to the `libstdc++.so` file version I'm linking with. If I alternate hiding and revealing this file I can get my program to link. However, I would like to be able to 'make' in one step as I did before I introduced the Boost libraries and concurrent threading.

Please help shed some light on this issue if you have any insight.

Comment: Can you show your linker command line?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install via `yum`.

`yum install boost`
You will not encouter such issues.

Try to include rpmforge and epel yum repositories.

Comment: You won't get Boost 1.53 from `yum`

Answer (score 0):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html#abi.versioning shows  that `GLIBCXX_3.4.9` is the symbol version used by the `libstdc++.so` from GCC 4.2.0, so if the Boost library wants that version then it means it was compiled with GCC 4.2.x

That means you can't use the library with a program linked by GCC 4.1.2, you need to link with GCC 4.2.0 or later

`libstdc++.so` is backward compatible but not forwards compatible, so you can compile a program with one version and link it to a newer version, but you can't compile with a newer version and link to an older version.

Comment: I attempted to link with version 4.2.4 of gcc only to experience the same issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You must be doing it wrong. If you link correctly with GCC 4.2 then you will get the `GLIBCXX_3.4.9` symbol versions.